# How to free large initialization data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a "best practice" for freeing large (dozens to hundreds of KB) of initialization data for a one-page web app.  The initialization data is being generated in large strings and array literals, but after being used the first time, isn't needed... the only condition under which it would be used again is if the user will reload the page, which brings in the source again.

I have no clue how to measure these techniques, to know if they are beneficial. Obviously they would only be particularly beneficial when the initialization strings and arrays are very large, the examples are small, though, for readability.

My first thought was to assign undefined to the variables, is in:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var initStr = "Think huge generated strings here",
      initArr = ["think", "big", "arrays", "of", "words", "or", "numbers", "or", "objects"];

function calledOnBodyLoad()
{ setup( initStr, initArr );
  initStr = undefined;
  initArr = undefined;
}

}());
```

But then it occurred to me that there is hidden initialization code that there is code in the IFFY to initialize the variables, and I didn't suppose it would be discarded... is the code for such IFFYs discardable after the initial use, even if the variables referenced stay around in the scope (considering other variables and other functions in the IFFY module)?

So then I wondered if it would be better to do something like this, in order to be able to explicitly discard the initialization code.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var initStr() = function() {
    return "Think huge generated strings here";
  },
      initArr() = function() {
    return ["think", "big", "arrays", "of", "words", "or", "numbers", "or", "objects"];
  };

function calledOnBodyLoad()
{ setup( initStr(), initArr());
  initStr = undefined;
  initArr = undefined;
}

}());
```

EDIT: in both examples, assume there is code somewhere that binds calledOnBodyLoad to the  tag.  And a whole bunch of other functions and variables inside the IFFY.

Comment: you don't need to free it, this is javascript; private variables cleanup after themselves.

Comment: Make sure to detach `calledOnBodyLoad` handler (if it was attached somewhere) after it's invoked and you're fine.

Comment: @dandavis unless they are not freed while there are references to them.

Comment: @zerkms: the outer anon means they are all private, and if they ARE needed, they won't be collected...

Comment: @dandavis "and if they ARE needed, they won't be collected" --- that's not entirely correct. "the outer anon means they are all private" -- it means the example is oversimplified since the `calledOnBodyLoad` is unreachable (so that it cannot be called on load).

Comment: granted, given this is not the whole code. but i stand by my advice of not worrying about it. and nothing needed later will be collected, that we can bank on. besides, saving a few hundred kb is insignificant in all but extreme edge-cases...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70170/discussion-between-zerkms-and-dandavis).